# Talend file name with date validation

Tags: java, validation, substring, talend

I need to check file name having timestamp with delimited "_" like

```
--->>>>> abc_def_gh_2014_12_25_08_54_04.txt
```

I need to get that timestamp and compare with date format. If it's true I need to move file to another location.

How to do it?

Comment: What have you tried, what did stop you?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fName = "abc_def_gh_2014_12_25_08_54_04.txt";
    String[] array = fName.split("_");
    if (array.length < 7)
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid Length");
    String strSeconds = array[array.length - 1].replace(".txt","");
    String strMinutes = array[array.length - 2];
    String strHours = array[array.length - 3];
    String strDay = array[array.length - 4];
    String strMonth = array[array.length - 5];
    String strYear = array[array.length - 6];

    // then convert to Integers
    Integer seconds = Integer.parseInt(strSeconds);
    // continue on with each variable, then add to Date     

}
```